# How to distinguish between PNMessage sent by current user versus those from others?

Tags: ios, pubnub

I am currently using PubNub to build chat-like functionality into an app. Following the example from the demo project, I added the following to my `viewDidLoad` to listen for messages received my channel:

```
[[PNObservationCenter defaultCenter] addMessageReceiveObserver:self withBlock:^(PNMessage *message) {
                                             NSLog(@"message %@", message);
                                             [self DisplayInLog: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]: %@",message.channel.name, message.message]];
                                             [self showReceivedMessage:message];
                                         }];
```

My problem is, when the current user sends a message using `[PubNub sendMessage:text toChannel:self.currentChannel]`, the listener picks up on the message (as expected), but I am having trouble distinguishing from the `PNMessage` that which is sent by the current user and which is sent by someone else and picked up by the receiver. How should I go about approaching this without getting too hacky (for example, comparing the contents of the messages, when they were sent, etc).

Thanks!

Comment: I'm in the same situation now. I'm trying to do it with the `requestHistoryForChannel`, where you can set the from: and to: value. In this case you will get an array with the messages, but i'm not sure that this is the right way.

Comment: A hacky workaround I found: since a received `PNMessage.message` is a kind of `[NSDictionary class]`, while a just sent `PNMessage.message` is a kind of `[NSString class]`, and therefore this could be used as a way to differentiate. Of course, a more official way would be helpful.

Comment: I was wrong, my version won't work, because the from and to is for the PNDate instead of channels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@daspianist

You have to add field which will store identifier of the user and on client side check who is sender of the message by retrieving value from dictionary which will be send as message.
For example:

```
[[PNObservationCenter defaultCenter] addMessageReceiveObserver:self withBlock:^(PNMessage *message) {

    NSLog(@"message %@", message);
    if (![[message.message valueForKey:@"sender"] isEqualToString:@"Bob"]) {

        [self DisplayInLog: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]: %@",message.channel.name, message.message]];
        [self showReceivedMessage:message];
    }
}];

[PubNub sendMessage:@{@"message":@"This is actual message which we want to send. It can be any Objective-C type.", @"sender":@"Bob"} toChannel:self.currentChannel];
```

In example above, it shouldn't process message if it has been sent from "**Bob**"

Comment: Possibly could you tell us too, what is the recommended solution to do this with the `requestHistoryForChannel` with block? Because it creates an array with PNMessage objects instead of a PNMessage, therefore i can't use this concept and also couldn't do an enumeration to get some specified messages based on the dictionary keys. Thank you

Comment: Thanks @moonlight - sending and retrieving my own specific set of key-value pair did the trick.

Comment: @sabin you can use same concept. As soon as you will send identity of the sender inside message, history will be filled by those "correct" messages and when you will pull out history, you will be able to iterate over the list of messages and filter it as you which taking into account sender identity.

Answer (score 0):

SEND MESSAGE IN DICTIONARY

```
NSDictionary *message = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"HELLLLOO",@"text",@"Kiran",@"sender", nil];
    [PubNub sendMessage:message toChannel:[PNDataManager sharedInstance].currentChannel
    withCompletionBlock:^(PNMessageState state, id object) {
}
```